# Defining array in array in array - php

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I am trying to create the following array dynamically:

```
$aSettings = array( "text"=> 
                  array( "icon_type" => 
                            array(
                                "name"=>"icon_type",
                                "method"=>"dropdown",
                                "option"=>"",
                                "default"=>""
                            ),
                          "column" => 
                            array(
                            "name"=>"column_count",
                            "method"=>"dropdown",
                            "default"=>"1"
                            )
                        )
                    )
```

I am not sure how to declare the array into the array.

I have the following example code:

```
$aSettings=array();
$aSetting_type['text']=array();
$aSetting_name['icon_type']=array();
$aSetting_name['column']=array();
$aSetting_values1=array('name'=>'icon_type','method'=>'dropdown','option'=>'','default'=>'');
$aSetting_values2=array('name'=>'column_count','method'=>'dropdown','default'=>1);
```

I guess I am overlooking something very simple, but how do I put all these arrays into each other?
I want to be able to call a value from the array as:

```
$aSettings['text']['column']['name'];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: understood the output, need more details regarding input i.e how is the array or data currently displayed when `var_dump` is used ? elaborate dynamically. and `$aSetting_values2` is not an array, it must throw an error.

Comment: You were correct about the typo's in the setting_values, I corrected that.

var dump:array(1) { ["text"]=> array(2) { ["icon_type"]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(9) "icon_type" ["method"]=> string(8) "dropdown" ["option"]=> string(0) "" ["default"]=> string(0) "" } ["column"]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(12) "column_count" ["method"]=> string(8) "dropdown" ["default"]=> int(1) } } }

Comment: with the vardump you have provided you should be able to fetch the value way you want, lets assume the var_dump was of array `$aSettings`, so `echo $aSettings['text']['column']['name'];` and the example code is not dynamic, you have manually written all the values, so we don't know whats coming dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$aSettings['text']['icon_type'] = $aSetting_values1;
$aSettings['text']['column'] = $aSetting_values2;
```

If you need it more dynamic, you could use variables like so:

```
$type = 'text';
$name1 = 'icon_type';
$aSettings[$type][$name1] = $aSetting_values1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect the array is reverse lower to higher order, it would be easy to collect without confusions, for example

```
$icon_type = array(
  "name"=>"icon_type",
  "method"=>"dropdown",
  "option"=>"",
  "default"=>""
);

$column =  array(
  "name"=>"column_count",
  "method"=>"dropdown",
  "default"=>"1"
);

$text = array( 
  "icon_type" => $icon_type,
  "column" => $column
);

$aSettings = array(
  "text"=> $text
);
```

Once you collect array like this you can easily access any element in the array i.e. `echo $aSettings['text']['column']['name'];`